# how to integrate Express Checkout on Mobile deveices using paypal for native android app

Tags: java, javascript, php, android, paypal

I was trying to integrate pay pal. I am getting login page but I am not getting the

> you don't  have pay pal... buy with card

option.

How can I get direct credit and debit card payment?